# MS Project equivalent to "xlAnd". Enumeration for logical operators

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-project

I'm trying to write a language independent filter for MS Project in VBA. I'm using the syntax:

```
FilterEdit (Name, Taskfilter, Create, Fieldname, Test, Value, Operation...)
```

I have managed to get the Fieldnames and Tests to be language independent, but I struggle with the `Operation:=` expression. For an English locale one would write: `Operation:="and"` but that doesnt work for other locales.

Is there a way to write the logical operator (and/or) as an enumeration? (not as a string?)

For Excel one could write `xlAnd`, and Project has a lot of enumerations starting with Pj, ie. `PjTaskStart`. I also know there's a `Filter.LogicalOperationType`, but I haven't managed to figure out if this could work for me or not. I have also experimented with `FieldConstantToFieldName`, but I reckon there's no fieldname for the logical operator?

I know I could use `If LocaleID = xxxx Then...`, but I'd like to not assume what locales will be in use.

**Edit:** I solved the first part of my problem!
By leaving it blank `Operation:=""`, Project returns "And". But I haven't figured out yet how to return "Or"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Operation:=""` works for FilterEdit, but not for SetAutoFilter.
So I ended up using the dreaded `If LocaleID`.

**Teaching moment:**

I found out most operators can be language independent, except for:

`And`, `Or`, `Contains` and `Does Not Contain`.
These needs to be translated for each locale.
 I'll get to those in a minute. First I'll list all the language independent operators:
`<`  Less than
 `<=` Less than or equal to 
 `>` Greater than 
 `>=` Greater than or equal to 
 `=` Equal to 
 `<>` Not equal to
My trick for finding the translations I need for the language dependent operators  is the following [MS Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-a-list-of-data-8ec38534-e2f1-41d0-b8bb-e3f5fcad95a0) page.

Notice the category named **"Filter for specific text"** in the English support page. Here we can read all the "words" we need. Now go to the bottom of the web page and change the language: [image: Button to switch Locale] 

This opens up a new page listing all the different languages (not locale specific). Remembering where you found the word for `Contains` in English, then changing the language to for instance "Magyar (Magyarorzág)", we can now see that `Contains = "Tartalmazza"` in Magyar.

Next step is to google "Magyar languge" and learn that this actually equals Hungarian. So now you can go to this [MSDN web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047(v=winembedded.10).aspx) to see that Hungarian = LocaleID: 1038.


Putting all this together inside VBA makes you have to write the following code:

```
Dim LocalContains As String

If LocaleID = 1038 Then
    LocalContains = "Tartalmazza" 'Hungarian
ElseIf LocaleID = 1044 Then
    LocalContains = "inneholder"  'Norwegian
Else
    LocalContains = "contains"    'English
End If
```